# newton's law of cooling ( Differential equations)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

A cold drink is brought into a warm room with initial temperature at 40F . A few mins later the drink is found to be 46F , after the same length of time , it becomes 51F . Use newton law of cooling to determine the temperature of the room ?

T(0)=40
dT/dt = k(T-Tm) , K is constant smaller than 0
T(t) = Tm + (T0 - Tm)e^kt
T=Temperature , t=Time , Tm = Temperature of the room 
We need to find Tm with this data that are shown in the question

Comment: Perhaps try demonstrating you've tried to solve the problem?

Comment: I put T(0)=90 
T(t) =Tm +(To-Tm)e^kt

Tm = Temperature of the room 
T= temperature , t = time

Comment: Please update the question with your attempt. From using the model you wrote in the comments, what would the answer to the question be?

Comment: @FadiMusleh Can you solve from the given hint? Let fell free to ask for further explanation.

Comment: unfortunately , i can not solve it from the given hint

Comment: @FadiMusleh I add some detail, but please show also your work.

Comment: subtract the two equations you gave me / 5=(40-Tm)e^-3rt

is this right ?? i facing a difficulty with solving it

Comment: (46-Troom)^2 = 91 
is this right ?

Comment: X = 46 - sqr(91) / x =46 + sqr(91) 
right ?

Comment: The right answer is that Troom = 76 ? 
True ?

Comment: @FadiMusleh Exactly! Well done

Comment: Thank you very much ! :)

Comment: @FadiMusleh You are welcome, Bye!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

We have that

$$\frac{dT}{dt}=r\Delta T\implies T(t)=T_{room}+(T_0-T_{room})e^{-rt}$$

then write down the givens and use $\log$ to find out $T_{room}$.

- $46=T_{room}+(40-T_{room})e^{-rt}\implies e^{-rt}=\frac{46-T_{room}}{40-T_{room}}\implies -rt=\log\left(\frac{46-T_{room}}{40-T_{room}}\right)$
- $51=T_{room}+(40-T_{room})e^{-2rt}\implies e^{-2rt}=\frac{51-T_{room}}{40-T_{room}}\implies -2rt=\log\left(\frac{51-T_{room}}{40-T_{room}}\right)$

thus

$$2\log\left(\frac{46-T_{room}}{40-T_{room}}\right)=\log\left(\frac{51-T_{room}}{40-T_{room}}\right)\iff \left(\frac{46-T_{room}}{40-T_{room}}\right)^2=\left(\frac{51-T_{room}}{40-T_{room}}\right)$$

$$(46-T_{room})^2=(51-T_{room})(40-T_{room})\implies T_{room}=76 $$